# Im getting an index out of bounds error even when i try subtractin one for a list (Unit testing)

Tags: python, unit-testing

Getting out of bounds error on my code even though it shouldn't be (as far as I can tell)

i've tried subtracting 1 from n which would account for starting at 0.

```
    import unittest
    import lecture.FirstProject


    class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
        def testShipping(self):
            weights = [29, 30, 31, 31, 33]
            expected = [5, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 6]
            for n in weights:
                expect = expected[n]
                actual = lecture.FirstProject.computeShippingCosts(n)
                self.assertEqual(expect, actual, "failed test  %n")
```

im expecting it to test each of these weights with the expected answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 for n in weights:
```

Iterates over all values in weights (29, 30, 31, 31, 33)

```
expect = expected[n]
```

tries to access index n from list `expected` which doesn't exist (index 29 in 1st iteration) thus raising an exception

To iterate over both lists you can do:

```
for weight, expect in zip(weights, expected):
    # do something with weight, expect
```

To iterate using indexes, you can do

```
for n in range(0, len(weights)):
    # do something with weights[n], expected[n]
```

Comment: shouldn't n just be the number of the index though, so 0, 1, 2.. etc

Comment: To get the index it might be better to use `for index, weight in enumerate(weights):`.

Comment: No,  ```in```  iterates over the values in the container/iterator not the indexes. If you want to iterate over indexes, you can use  the ```range()``` function . You could also use the ```enumerate()``` function which returns both a value and an index.
[https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp) has a good explanation on python iterators

Comment: @ZachLynessSonicEX yes, n can only be integers 0,1,2, and so on. In your case the index of weights and expected is from 0 to 4 because both the lists have 5 elements. expected[29] or expected[30] or expected[31] or expected[33]  do not exists.

Comment: ok I understand that. so instead what ive done is created another variable I in the for loop initialized at 0 and everytime it runs it adds one. but  it then says some of my testing answers are wrong (which they were) but then I fixed them. and it still seems to be outputting the wrong answers

Comment: My guess is that in the for loop the variable value is reaching to 5 after last iteration so it is throwing the same error.